# Implementing ajax calls based on scrollbar position - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have noticed that in Google web reader (that lets us read RSS feeds on the web), the page does not seem to load ALL the feeds. Instead, as I scroll down, I can see more and more feeds (and the size of the scrollbar increases if you know what i mean)

I assume they do this by finding the position of the scrollbar and do an AJAX call. Is this correct? How would I do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: Those darn google programmers they always have some sort of cool UI design going.  Just like their fade into their home page...err!

Comment: For some value of "cool". Frankly, having a scroll bar handle with a length that doesn't represent the data that is actually available is a UI design choice I dislike immensely.

Comment: @David - But the way google seems to handle it is really good, they have the same sort of thing going on with Android Devices.  They make stuff intuitive and friendly to use and that is what is seperating companies like Microsoft from Google and Apple.

Comment: @David - I am sure it helps in performance as well. Imagine the overhead if you wanted to display 1000s of pictures on a single web page. Loading them intelligently this way helps the load time on the page

Comment: @JonH — The way Yahoo! (in their Mail app) handle it is better — the scrollbar actually reflects the amount of scrolling the user can do, and the user can scroll to any point in the document (and then let that section load if it hasn't already) rather then scrolling to the end, waiting for data to load, scrolling a bit further, and so on. "Different from every other application on the computer" is not "intuitive" or "friendly".

Comment: @David Dorward - I guess it really depends on the user.  I seem to like what path Apple and Google are headed when it comes to their applications.  But again this is my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET side of things is no different from any other HTTP response — you just provide the requested data.

The trick here is to check how far the browser has scrolled and make the request if it has scrolled however far you determine is far enough. You can use [the scroll event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html).